# Package varnish requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)

Tags: pcre, varnish

I am trying to install varnish on CentOS 6.5 VM, i am getting this error

```
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) for package: varnish-libs-3.0.5-1.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: varnish-libs-3.0.5-1.el6.x86_64 (varnish-3.0)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: varnish-3.0.5-1.el6.x86_64 (varnish-3.0)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I tried reinstalling pcre-devel and many other packages. It says package already installed. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue related to docker image. When i switched over to tavisto/centos-java-base image, the problem was fixed.